# Mongo db query optimization

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongo db to store notifications, a `cron` job runs every midnight to pick old notification and delete them.

The deletion policy has a logic to retain the oldest notification of each combination of  `"sourceObjectIdentifier"` and `"notificationType"`. The aggregated output of query 1 is given to query 2 to form the deletion query.

**query 1** -

```js
db.persistentEvent.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "notificationClass": {"$eq": "category"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": [
        {"sourceObjectIdentifier": "$sourceObjectIdentifier"},
        {"notificationType": "$notificationType"}
      ],
      "notificationId": {"$last": "$notificationId"},
      "notificationClass": {"$last": "$notificationClass"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "notificationId": 1,
      "notificationClass": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "sourceObjectIdentifier": 1,
      "notificationType": 1,
      "creationTime": -1
    }
  }
])
```

**query 2** -

```json
{
  "deliveryTime": {
    "$gt": "$datefrom"
  },
  "creationTime": {
    "$lt": "dateto"
  },
  "notificationId": {
    "$nin": [query_1_output]
  }
}
```

This deletion logic works fine if the number of notifications in the collection is less but it starts to take a long time when the number of notifications are in range 200k or above.

Can someone please suggest how can I improve the query and can the query 1 and 2 be executed together?

Comment: What is "a long time"? What is the desired time? How many notifications are you typically processing? What are the indexes on the collection? What is the `.explain("allPlansExecution")` output for the queries? Can you provide sample documents?

Comment: Also, you're using `$last` but I don't see a `$sort` in your pipeline. Are you getting correct results? The docs have [this warning about the operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#mongodb-group-grp.-last):"_Only meaningful when documents are in a defined order._"

Comment: Is it really the goal to keep the oldest notifications and delete the new ones?

Comment: I am surprised that this query works as intended. It does not select the **newest** notification (i.e. the notification with the newest creationTime), it selects the notification which was inserted last. Is the order of inserting the same order as the actual notifications? I am not familiar with the deep internals of MongoDB, but when you delete big amount of data, then MongoDB may write new data into released spaces and then the order of documents would change.

Comment: @user20042973 if you look towards the end of query 1 , the sorting is also added

Comment: An `$sort` at the end has no effect on previous `$last`. Also if you like to use the result as value in `$nin`, the order does not matter. Thus the last `$sort` only slows down your query - nothing more. Apart from that, `$nin` should contain a plain list of values rather than objects. It is really hard to believe that your query is working at all.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes I doubt it worked as it was expected to work. This issue was not noticed as the cleanup of older notification was not failing for smaller dataset. Recently the functionality was tested with large set of notifications and it just takes forever to complete the cleanup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how you define "newest notification".

- The notification which was inserted most recently?
- The notification with the greatest `notificationId`?
- The notification with the newest `creationTime`?

First ensure that you have an index on the `notificationClass`. A composed index on `{sourceObjectIdentifier: 1, notificationType: 1}` may also help.

Use `$setWindowFields` to find the newest notifications (rank = 1), and delete all others. Below command considers "newest notification" as notification with the newest `creationTime`.

```
var deleteDocs = [];
db.persistentEvent.aggregate([
   { $match: { notificationClass: "category" } },
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         partitionBy: {
            sourceObjectIdentifier: "sourceObjectIdentifier",
            notificationType: "$notificationType"
         },
         sortBy: { creationTime: -1 },
         output: {
            rank: { $rank: {} },
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { rank: { $gt: 1 } } },
   { $project: { _id: 1 } }
]).toArray().forEach(doc => {
   deleteDocs.push(doc._id);
   if (deleteDocs.length > 10000) {
      db.persistentEvent.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: deleteDocs } });
      deleteDocs = [];
   }
})
if (deleteDocs.length > 0)
   db.persistentEvent.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: deleteDocs } });
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wWkwNs7BUjO)

Answer (score 0):

As written, query 1 will scan far more documents than is really necessary.
Also, by the time the sort stage is encountered, the group stage and project stage will have removed all fields except `notificationId` and `notificationClass`.  This means none of the fields in the sort object will exist, so that sort will accomplish nothing.

To improve this query:

- move the sort stage to before the group stage
- create an index that includes the match field and the sort fields
- if the 5 fields mention in this query do not constitute the vast majority of the size of each document, also add `notificationId` to the index.

If the query executor is able to select and sort the documents based on the index, that will eliminate the need to load non-matching documents from storage, and will avoid an in-memory sort.  Both of these will help performance.

If the documents are significantly larger than the combination of `notificationClass`, `notificationId`,  `sourceObjectIdentifier`, `notificationType`, and `creationTime`, creating an index containing those fields, following the ESR rule will permit query 1 to be satisfied using only the information included in the index, making it a covered query:

```
{
   notificationClass: 1,
   sourceObjectIdentifier: 1,
   notificationType: 1,
   creationTime: -1,
   notificationId: 1
}
```

With the above index this pipeline should perform significantly better than the existing query as the collection grows:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "notificationClass": {"$eq": "category"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "sourceObjectIdentifier": 1,
      "notificationType": 1,
      "creationTime": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": [
        {"sourceObjectIdentifier": "$sourceObjectIdentifier"},
        {"notificationType": "$notificationType"}
      ],
      "notificationId": {"$last": "$notificationId"},
      "notificationClass": {"$last": "$notificationClass"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "notificationId": 1,
      "notificationClass": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't see any improvement even after moving the sort up in the pipeline

Comment: If you've already created the index, run the query using explain with the execution stats option.  That will show you how much time is spent on each stage.