# MongoDB - lookup is not working after group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My initial requirement is remove all documents (not from the collection) those are unique with a field `itemId` value. My query is working fine to remove the unique documents -

```
db.contents.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            {
                $and: [
                    { widgetId: new ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2") },
                    { value: 'Yes' }
                ]
            },
            {
                $and: [
                    { widgetId: new ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f9") },
                    {
                        value: "40"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$itemId",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        contents: {
            $push: {
                _id: "$_id",
                value: "$value",
                label: "$label",
                widgetId: "$widgetId",
                itemId: "$itemId"
            }
        },
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        count: {
            $gte: 2
        }
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$contents" },
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$contents._id",
        label: { "$first": "$contents.label" },
        value: { "$first": "$contents.value" },
        widgetId: { "$first": "$contents.widgetId" },
        itemId: { "$first": "$contents.itemId" }
    }
}
])
```

Here is the result from the above query -

```
[{
_id: ObjectId("648d5199221f77c425aac223"),
label: 'Featured Product',
value: 'Yes',
widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2"),
itemId: ObjectId("648d5199221f77c425aac21a")
}
{
_id: ObjectId("648d5131221f77c425aac1b7"),
label: 'Discount',
value: '40',
widgetId: ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f9"),
itemId: ObjectId("648d5131221f77c425aac1b0")
}
{
_id: ObjectId("648d5131221f77c425aac1b9"),
label: 'Featured Product',
value: 'Yes',
widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2"),
itemId: ObjectId("648d5131221f77c425aac1b0")
}
{
_id: ObjectId("648d50d3221f77c425aac160"),
label: 'Discount',
value: '40',
widgetId: ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f9"),
itemId: ObjectId("648d50d3221f77c425aac146")
}
{
_id: ObjectId("648d50d3221f77c425aac162"),
label: 'Featured Product',
value: 'Yes',
widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2"),
itemId: ObjectId("648d50d3221f77c425aac146")
}
{
_id: ObjectId("648d5199221f77c425aac221"),
label: 'Discount',
value: '40',
widgetId: ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f9"),
itemId: ObjectId("648d5199221f77c425aac21a")
}]
```

But end of the query, when I try to restore my all documents with missing properties via `lookup` from the same collection, then the query does not work.

```
db.contents.aggregate([
........
........
........
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "contents",
        localField: "itemId",
        foreignField: "itemId",
        as: "contents"
    }
}
])
```

**Edit:**

Here are some additional documents those I am trying to append again via the `lookup` -

```
{
   "_id": {
     "$oid": "648d5199221f77c425aac21d"
   },
   "widgetType": "input",
   "label": "Name",
   "itemId": {
     "$oid": "648d5199221f77c425aac21a"
   },
   "formId": {
     "$oid": "648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f5"
   },
   "slug": "name",
   "value": "FITTED DRESS",
   "trashed": "false",
   "status": 1,
   "widgetId": {
     "$oid": "648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f7"
   },
   "createdAt": {
     "$date": "2023-06-17T06:24:25.417Z"
   },
   "updatedAt": {
     "$date": "2023-06-19T14:07:42.600Z"
   },
   "disabled": "false"
}
{
   "_id": {
     "$oid": "648d5199221f77c425aac21e"
   },
   "widgetType": "input",
   "label": "Slug",
   "itemId": {
     "$oid": "648d5199221f77c425aac21a"
   },
   "formId": {
     "$oid": "648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f5"
   },
   "slug": "slug",
   "value": "fitted-dress",
   "trashed": "false",
   "status": 1,
   "widgetId": {
     "$oid": "648d419bae1b9fb2af57f967"
   },
   "createdAt": {
     "$date": "2023-06-17T06:24:25.417Z"
   },
   "updatedAt": {
     "$date": "2023-06-19T14:07:42.600Z"
   },
   "disabled": "false"
}
{
   "_id": {
     "$oid": "648d5199221f77c425aac21f"
   },
   "widgetType": "input",
   "label": "Price",
   "itemId": {
     "$oid": "648d5199221f77c425aac21a"
   },
   "formId": {
     "$oid": "648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f5"
   },
   "slug": "price",
   "value": "174",
   "trashed": "false",
   "status": 1,
   "widgetId": {
     "$oid": "648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f8"
   },
   "createdAt": {
     "$date": "2023-06-17T06:24:25.417Z"
   },
   "updatedAt": {
     "$date": "2023-06-19T14:07:42.600Z"
   },
   "disabled": "false"
}
```

Comment: Can you add some original documents from the collection as well?

Comment: I added some documents @Charchit

Comment: Instead of `$unwind` and `$group`, you may use `$setWindowFields`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76458894/mongo-db-query-optimization/76461880#76461880 which is almost the same requirement as yours.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the query doesn't work? Does it throw an error, give unexpected results, something else?

Comment: I am executing the query in my MongoDB Compass shell. When I execute the query the compass get hanged and white screen. But same query without the `lookup` it works fine. It does not throw any error.